# Discord python bot: how do I find out how long a server member has been in that server for?

Tags: python, discord

I just started learning how to code a discord bot with python. What I want one of its functions to do is to find out how long a server member has been a part of a server for, but I have absolutely no idea on how to code it. If anyone knows how to do this, could I see some example code?

Comment: Can you add dome description of how you're interacting with Discord from Python? Are you using discord.py, interacting with their web API directly, or something else?

Comment: So I am using something called replit to host the app, and my code interacts with the api directly.

Comment: You want the endpoint here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-member

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.